# flyctl launch: Error name argument or flag must be specified when not running interactively

Tags: deployment, fly

I am trying to deploy a flask app in fly.io, but when execute `flyctl launch` in the terminal I get an error:
**Error** name argument or flag must be specified when not running interactively.

I don't see any other way to make a deployment in fly.io other than the console. I tried with a Dockerfile but `flyctl launch` continue throwing the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently flyctl believes you're not running its command-line tool interactively. That may or may not be a bug of flyctl itself, you can ask about that in the [fly.io community](https://community.fly.io/).

The solution to this problem is to add the required information as parameters instead of being prompted for data entry. To my knowledge, you only need the *name* of the app you want to launch and the [region code](https://fly.io/docs/reference/regions/#fly-io-regions) of the server location. The syntax for that can be found using the `fly help launch` command:

```
λ flyctl help launch
Create and configure a new app from source code or a Docker image.

Usage:
  flyctl launch [flags]

Flags:
      --auto-confirm                  Will automatically confirm changes when running non-interactively.
      --build-arg strings             Set of build time variables in the form of NAME=VALUE pairs. Can be specified multiple times.
      --build-only                    Build but do not deploy
      --build-secret strings          Set of build secrets of NAME=VALUE pairs. Can be specified multiple times. See https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information
      --build-target string           Set the target build stage to build if the Dockerfile has more than one stage
      --copy-config                   Use the configuration file if present without prompting
      --detach                        Return immediately instead of monitoring deployment progress
      --dockerfile string             Path to a Dockerfile. Defaults to the Dockerfile in the working directory.
      --dockerignore-from-gitignore   If a .dockerignore does not exist, create one from .gitignore files
  -e, --env strings                   Set of environment variables in the form of NAME=VALUE pairs. Can be specified multiple times.
      --generate-name                 Always generate a name for the app, without prompting
  -i, --image string                  The Docker image to deploy
      --image-label string            Image label to use when tagging and pushing to the fly registry. Defaults to "deployment-{timestamp}".
      --local-only                    Only perform builds locally using the local docker daemon
      --name string                   Name of the new app
      --nixpacks                      Deploy using nixpacks to generate the image
      --no-cache                      Do not use the build cache when building the image
      --no-deploy                     Do not prompt for deployment
      --now                           Deploy now without confirmation
  -o, --org string                    The target Fly organization
      --path string                   Path to the app source root, where fly.toml file will be saved (default ".")
      --push                          Push image to registry after build is complete
  -r, --region string                 The target region (see 'flyctl platform regions')
      --remote-only                   Perform builds on a remote builder instance instead of using the local docker daemon
      --strategy string               The strategy for replacing running instances. Options are canary, rolling, bluegreen, or immediate. Default is canary, or rolling when max-per-region is set.

Global Flags:
  -t, --access-token string   Fly API Access Token
  -j, --json                  json output
      --verbose               verbose output
```

In summary, the following command, executed in the directory of the app you want to launch on fly.io, should create an app called *your-app-name* in the Toronto, Canada location.

```
flyctl launch --name your-app-name --region yyz
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I used the correct parameters. The problem was that I was using Git Bash terminal on windows, so I switched to PowerShell and it works perfect.

Comment: I still have the same issue with PowerShell and cmd.  flyctl.exe v0.0.441